# Need python code example - setting a combo listbox to Null

Tags: python, arcpy, combo-box

I want to be able to set the value of a field to Null using python, but I get an error.
I am using arcpy.CalculateField_management

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code and the error message?

Comment: You do not say what your data format is. If your source dataset is a shapefile then you cannot set the field to Null as dBase format does not support it.

Answer (score 2):

Not using field-calculator, you can use UpdateCursor and setNull.
(Arcgis for [10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000008r000000))

a quick example:

```
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc, sql, etc...)
for row in rows:
    row.SetNull("FIELD")
rows.updateRow(row)
del rows
```

Comment: Great!, but I am using Arc 10.0 and we are not moving to 10.1 or awhile.

Comment: It's about the same in [10.0](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Row/000v000000nv000000/).  The same method will work.